# Discord.py ReWrite - @has_permissions not working correctly

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I have the command defined like this

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No Reason Provided")
```

And when the server owner and admin tries to do it I get a

> MissingPermissions Error

Any Idea for why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have ```has_permissions``` explicitly imported? Because if not, you may try ```commands.has_permissions``` or even ```discord.ext.commands.permissions```

Comment: Yes i do "from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions"

Comment: Does the *bot* have the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that the Bot cannot ban a user that has a role above its highest role.